# C# Integration with ATM Swipe Machine

Tags: c#, integration

I want to seek some help or suggestion or reference links around, how to achieve an integration between Windows application and ATM swipe machine.

Suppose if we have an Billing system and Customer wants to pay by ATM Debit/Credit Card. So if I want to send an Amount for the bill to ATM Swipe machine so that it can accept the amount and once pay button is pressed on ATM swipe machine the appropriate amount should be deducted.

Basically **only intention is to send Amount to Swipe machine through C# application**

If possible - It should be for any Bank and once the ATM card is inserted into swipe machine, else it should detect card not present.

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on which machine you are interfacing with as there is no universal standard that we could tell you "how to do it". Each manufacturer has its own method and each method is totally different from the other methods.

Check the SDK for the device you are planning to use as a card processor to see and figure out what you need to do to communicate with it.